# How can I sum top 5 values from column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a simple table wherein `A2`-`A100` I have numbers. I want to sum 5 highest numbers and save in `A1`. What is a proper query to do this? I tried to do `QUERY` with `SELECT` but I couldn't enforce to sum only the top 5 numbers.

```
-|----------|
 | A        |
-|----------|
1| Sum here |
2| 938      |
3| 124      |
4| 544      |
5| 453      |
6| 632      |
7| 324      |
8| ...more  |
-|----------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably one of many ways:

```
=sum(query(sort(A2:A100,1,false), "select Col1 limit 5",0))
```

Answer (score 3):

...or with sortn:

```
=sum(sortn(A2:A,5,0,A2:A,false))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUM(QUERY(A2:A, "order by A desc limit 5", 0))
```

[image: 0]